# Export bullet physics with the Y and Z axis swapped

Tags: scripting, game-engine, export

I'm using the script example used in Blender's physics documentation:

```
import PhysicsConstraints
PhysicsConstraints.exportBulletFile("Physics.bullet")
```

The problem is that the Y and Z axis appear to be swapped when the data is loaded at runtime by a third party game engine. Is there a way to swap the coordinates before exporting to the .bullet file?

Can this swapping be automated in the script?

[A video showing how the script is used](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv-Oq5oe8Nw)

As a side note, the bullet exporter is not an add-on exporter, but rather a feature of the physics engine module.

Comment: Is this a Blender library? Would you mind linking to it?

Comment: @CharlesL http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Physics

Answer (score 1):

according this post [Is it possible to make Blender a Y-up world?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/471/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-a-y-up-world)
not really, though most exporters have an option to flip it.

Comment: Bullet exporter is not an add-on exporter, but rather a feature of the physics engine module

Comment: @rraallvv it would be more useful for you to add this information to your question.