# Why does Blender have the Z-axis up but is the depth-pass actually called a Z-pass?

Tags: terminology

I understand what it does, but it doesn't make sense. The terms used might be confusing for new users.

Answer (score 8):

Because 3D space and image space are unrelated.

- It makes sense that you have `(X, Y)` used for a 2D image, so then its logical that the depth be `Z`.
- Which axis represents 'depth' in 3D space is undefined, there is no right answer and it's not consistent between applications, if you work with maps it may make sense that `(X, Y)` are for a 2D top-down view and Z is the land height. But you can rationalize this differently too, so what makes sense to you is probably based on the applications or use-cases you've previously been used to.

Comment: OP can also see [Is it possible to make Blender a Y-up world?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/471/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-a-y-up-world) for a bit more info.