# Rotating face downwards

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to rotate a face downwards so that it looks like this:
[image]

I have not been able to do this by the R and any Shift+Z or X, Y or Y command. 
This is just a fake screenshot where I moved the vertices manually, to demonstrate what it should look like.

Thank you.

I have uploaded the model here:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37734

Comment: Try to change transform orientation to normal and hit R, Y, Y

Comment: with the selected faces use G (grab) and move it down over the Z-axis, then select the edges on the bottom and scale over the x and y (shift + Z)

Comment: @Denis Thanks, this is the solution. However, it does not work when I have multiple faces selected at the same time. Do you also have a solution for this?

Comment: @tmighty Yes you can switch Pivot Point to Individual origins to achieve that

Comment: Somewhat related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21248/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the faces you want to rotate, Change Pivot Point to **Individual Origins**, Transform Orientation to **Normal** and hit <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to rotate the faces

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### Rotate using the 3D cursor as a pivot

With <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> you can snap the cursor to the geometry. Than set the Pivot to 3D cursor and rotate on the wanted axis.

[image]

Comment: I think you mean [Shift]+[S].

Comment: @PGmath Sorry, wrong letter! I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish what you wish is to use vertex select mode, and select the vertex at the joint between the tab and the body of the barrel nearest the arrowhead in the lower image of the screenshot, and shown as selected in the screenshot below:

[[image]]

Next, using the "cursor to selected" option of the snap tool (<kbd>SHFT</kbd> - <kbd>S</kbd>, relocate the 3D cursor to that vertex, and change the pivot point to 3D cursor. Then making sure the barrel is rotated so the line between the center of the barrel and the tab you want to rotate is parallel with a major axis (X or Y), select the two faces you want to rotate, and rotate them along the perpendicular axis. You may need to rotate the barrel to fix the additional tabs.

Alternatively, you might adjust your workflow so that you create three staves of the barrel, including two with the tabs rotated, and one without a tab, and apply the array modifier to the mesh to create the rest of the body of the barrel. This will be quicker than moving each of the tabs individually.