# How to Micro Manage Manipulator

Tags: transforms, vertices, 3d-manipulator

When in *Edit Mode*, I find sometimes I want to move an edge, or at least two vertices, in a direction that would be perpendicular to their orientation along their existing edge.

At that moment, the *Transformation Orientation* selections (Normal, Local, Global, *et al*) have no vectors pointing in that direction.

How might I, or is it possible to, change the "polarity" of those manipulator vectors (independent of the given selections: *Global*, *Local*, *Normal*, *Gimble*, *View*) so that one of them is pointing in the perpendicular direction to the line/edge between the vertices?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21248/599

Comment: You can create [custom orientation](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html#custom-orientations) as explained in [Extrude edge along roof angle](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38482/extrude-edge-along-roof-angle/38487#38487) but you'll need at least a face to define an orientation. Could you better explain your example?

Comment: @Carlo You can create an orientation with just an edge, two disconnected verts, or even a single vertex (using the line from the object's origin).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4965/599

Comment: @gandalf3 !!! Mhhh, I tried before writing that: maybe I wasn't paying enough attention. I'll investigate!

Answer (score 7):

Enter *Edit Mode*, switch to *Edge* selection mode, select any edge, go to the *Transform Orientations* panel and press the *+* button to add a new transform orientation while that edge is selected.

You can name your new transform orientation whatever you want, and then use it afterwards. There will additionally be created a new transform orientation named "Edge" that will hold the orientation you want.

You can then move along that edge direction, or perpendicularly to it, relative to the surrounding faces normals.

[image]