# How can I make it so the move tool is on the object?

Tags: 3d-view

When I import a model from ROBLOX, it offsets the model from the tool if the model was not built in the center in ROBLOX. It is very frustrating to work with parts when the move/rotate tool is somewhere super distant in the world.

[image]

I haven't been able to find a solution to make it so that the tool is on the object like so: 
[image]

What can I do so that I have the move/rotate tool centered to my model?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52049/how-to-micro-manage-manipulator

Comment: That tool is actually called widget and it is on the object since the object origin is far off. You can repair the location of the object origin with CTRL SHIFT ALT C >> origin to geometry. I rarely ever use the widgets. I prefer shortcuts.