# Change the angle pivot of my object

Tags: modeling

This is my first question! :D I'm ultra noob! but I'm getting better and better.

So: I want to change the angle of the pivot of this object.

[image: 1]
Is like this now.

[image: 2]
But when I want make a scale in X axis, this is happend.

[image: 3]
So I belive that is one solution is change the axis like this for the scale thing... right?

How I can do that!

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Micro Manage Manipulator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52049/how-to-micro-manage-manipulator)

Comment: Possibly press `S` to scale, and then press `XX` to scale over the local X-axis instead of the global one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let's you have this setup here, similar to yours:

   [image] 
   Cylinder fits 2 cubes, but it's orientation is broken. And you want to fix it.
2. Create a **Custom Transform Orientation**. For this simple example: select the edge you want to align, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> or find it at bottom of the <kbd>N</kbd>-Panel.

   You will have a new transform orientation that fits to geometry:

   [image]
3. Now you can use this transform orientation for scale your object. But If you want to align object itself, move next.
4. In object Mode select cylinder, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> -> **Cursor to Selected**
5. Create empty then press **Object** -> **Transform** -> **Align to transform Orientation**.
6. Parent cylinder to the empty  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.
7. Clear empty's orientation <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. Cylinder will follow empty and will rotate with it like this:

   [image]
8. Unparent cylinder <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> -> **Clear and keep transform**.
9. Apply rotation to cylinder  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> -> **Rotation**
10. Rotate cylinder back ( **Object** -> **Transform** -> **Align to transform Orientation**. )

[image]

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST! :*