# Arrows show wrong axes

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, scale, 3d-cursor

Arrows show wrong axes. Something went wrong with the axes and they began to show absolutely wrong directions. Maybe someone know how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Please improve the clarity of your question. Please show the entire screen including headers and footers.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52049/how-to-micro-manage-manipulator/52050#52050

Answer (score 2):

Change the transformation axis as indicated by the Yellow Arrow below.
Try the different selections to see the effects.

[image]

Transformation Axis.

Sometimes a stray keystroke can have an unintended effect.  So many keystrokes.