# Can I make Blender a Y-Up world?

Tags: customization, coordinates

After using other 3D Apps I have become used to Y being up, and Z being depth (Depth pass, Z pass etc).

Is there a way to make Blender a Y-up world, and if not, does anyone know why they chose to be different ?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate Question. See: [Is it possible to make Blender a Y-up world?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/471/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-a-y-up-world?rq=1)

["The standard orientation, where the xy-plane is horizontal and the z-axis points up"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#In_three_dimensions) is part of the Right Handed Orientation coordinate system. It is not "being different" as much a choice between Left or Right Handed systems. Each design team makes there own choices when they first start coding.

Comment: This is incorrect, the handedness of a coordinate system refers to which direction the z-axis points relative to the x and y axes and is separate from which axis is up. For example the conventional coordinate system for CAD applications is right-handed with z up while the one for VFX and animation software is right-handed with y up.