# Import a bvh file and export it to be the same

Tags: animation, export, armature, import

I have a bvh file found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ww124hr3ut6kuj/original.bvh?dl=0) and I want to import it to blender, then export it again so that both the original (imported) and exported bvh files are identical. I'm not sure what options I should choose to import and export the bvh files so if anyone could please advise.

When I keep the default options to import and export, then open the bvh files, they are totally different, this is the resulted [bvh file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1jwka38hvemhqo/result_export.bvh?dl=0).

So if anyone could please advise.

Comment: Blender uses the Z axis for up, whereas many other 3D software packages use the Y axis. This looks like a confusion between these conventions. This is quite possibly a bug, where Blender compensates for its own different convention on import, but "forgets" to do so on export.

Comment: @SixthOfFour so would you please advise me with a way on how to import the original and export it to be the same?

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I made a small edit after you accepted, about a possible workaround for the rotation.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Thank you very much! you are a legend :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked a little closer and found a solution. On importing, there's an option to set which axes point up and forward. Set those to Z up and Y forward.
[image: BVH import options]

Here's the original file with the axes set like that:
[image: Original file]

And here's after exporting it and re-importing it with the axes set like that:
[image: Exported then re-imported file]

As you can see the entire scene gets rotated when you do this, but the files are essentially identical. A possible workaround would be to import with the axes set to their defaults, and when you're done working with it, select **everything** and rotating it by -90° around the X axis before exporting. Snap the 3D cursor to the world centre (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>R</kbd>) and set the pivot point to 3D cursor before rotating.
[image: Set pivot point]

Comment: Related, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/471/12

Comment: @iKlsR To me Blender's convention is what comes naturally (most likely because of my math background), and I never even considered Y-up before I started using 3D software. A link in a comment to that question explained to me why some software uses Y-up. Thank you for that.