# how to change how rotation of middle click when viewing model in layout

Tags: 3d-view

I am trying to view my model in Blender and I would like to change the controls a bit.
Right now, when I press down on my scroll wheel (middle click), and then move my mouse left-to-right, I am rotating my view of the model about the Z-axis of the blender-model world frame. When I middle-click and push the mouse up-and-down, I am rotating my view about the view-matrix X-axis (the X-axis if this were an OpenGL window). In other words, it looks as if I am at the top of a hill and I push the blender model down the hill.

What I would really like to have happen when I middle click and drag sideways is to have the blender model rotate about the view-matrix Y-Axis, like you would on a trackball-style mouse. In other words, if I push the model "down a hill", I have a birds-eye-view of the model rolling down the hill.

How do I change the layout model viewing rotation behavior as described?

This looks like what I [want](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36049/rotate-view-around-vertical-y-axis?rq=1), but it is a really old answer. Is there an updated version of this? I use blender 2.90.X

Comment: I think "trackball" (the linked answer in your question) is what you describe. Or? Can be found in "navigation" tab in 2.9

Comment: The interface looks different there, and, I am not sure what settings solve my specific issue since they simply provide a screenshot. What settings in the new interface have to be changed? After thinking about it, trackball is definitely what I want, not what the current default is. I am not sure what specific setting button to change.

Comment: Have edited the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45127/19156

Comment: Yes, that screenshot solves this question.