# Homogeneous Matrix Wrong Orientation from Blender, come from PyOpenGL

Tags: python, modeling, animation, game-engine

Good afternoon guys, I have an animation in PyOpenGL, which receives the coordinates of a file, and then animates an ROV.

This animation calculates the homogeneous ROV matrix containing its position and Orientation in certain instants of animation, (Ex, 10 seconds of animation are 2000 lines of coordinates "X Y Z").

I'm bringing this simulation to Blender, for working on it creating a more real world for animation.

But I'm having problems.

I have a CAD Object that is an ROV, and when I step at all instants of the animation this Homogeneous Matrix, the position of the ROV is correct, but the orientation of it goes wrong, inside the Blender.

It seems that Phi, Theta and Csi are reversed. The orientation should go to the left, but it appears going right. How can I check this and change the orientation of the object, which is being passed by the homogeneous Matrix:

Would anyone help me understand why this occurs?

Blender work with Matrix Homogeneous different from OpenGL?

Codes:
Sample Matrix homogeneous:

```
posture =
[ 0.21468954 -0.86920989 -0.4454017  -1.61063969 
  0.65986419 -0.20712563  0.72227293  2.18389297 
 -0.72006083 -0.44896907  0.52909279 -7.34360504 
  0.  0.  0.  1.]

self.owner.localTransform = posture
```

Result: 
[image: Rov should be in the right orientation, with his forehead elevated. He is inverted and with the front pointing down]

Rov should be in the right orientation, with his forehead elevated. He is inverted and with the front pointing down.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You might have to check on your object local axis orientation.

Comment: Hi hawkenfox, I put Euler XYZ. If I change to Euler YXZ, ZYX, XZY, ... there is no change in the animation.

Comment: Blender uses the [right hand orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)) and has the [z-axis pointing up](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/473/935) does that match what you used in pyopengl?

Comment: Thanks @sambler , I found out what's wrong, in Blender I have to Z-UP, but I need Z to be DOWN. I tried to change my object by enabling the "Inverted Z depth" option on the property, but I did not succeed, nothing has changed. I tried to export my CAD object as "FBX" and put the "UP" "-Z UP" and "Z UP" option, and import it into blender, but also did not change the animation. It was the same, inverted. How do I invert the Blender to Z = Down, or invert the Z?

Comment: Not my thing - the [fbx importer](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_fbx/import_fbx.py;fa076be65f7de830f5d51bbd1f674ec582175f5a$2314) uses [`axis_conversion`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy_extras.io_utils.html#bpy_extras.io_utils.axis_conversion) from `bpy_extras.io_utils`