# Setting up user preferences

Tags: interface

I love the look of Blender after after many years of not paying it any attention - the features look great si I would like to start learning and using it.
However, I'm stuck at the beginning of just setting it up.
I'm coming from Modo, Lightwave and Maya and this is how I want to control it. The Maya preset is not enough, and I don't want to adapt to the Blender right click.
When I set it up to mouse Left click and combination of Alt, Shift or Alt+Shift for screen navigation, I then cannot select between verts, edges and polys.

Is there a way to set this up or do I have to accept the Blender way of doing things?

Also, the axis are changed from 'normal' - is thera way to change the Y axis to up and down and have Z for depth?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That does it mean "cannot select between verts, edges and polys" Ctrl+tab doesn't works?

Comment: Sorry, user error! Ctrl+tab does now work - even though i think it wasn't before it is now - I'm sure I was doing something wrong as I have had to reset to factory many times as I have been messing about in the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I Can give you some tips, you can change all inputs you need in Blender, in the Blender User Preferences Panel:
[image]

As you can see, I highlight a input I mapped to  my own workflow, the Edge Loop Selection to the input Alt+Select Mouse. Each input have advanced properties you can set, as well a combination of inputs to execute it.
[image]

Here I show you a default shortcut for a great deal of tools for Blender 2.73, although mostly of the shortcuts stay the same.

[image]

So, while yes, you can change and map each input to your liking, it's not advised to do so, Blender it's a different software than Modo, Maya, 3DsMax, so I recommend you to use Blender the way it is, you will get used to it just like you are confortable working in your favorite softwares.

For your to change Y axis to Z, here's a relatable question: [Is it possible to make Blender a Y-up world?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/471/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-a-y-up-world)

Comment: Thankyou, this is very helpful. I will try your setup, but if it's best to just adapt to the Blender way then I'll keep that in mind. That image you posted is a great resource!